# Command Line Find & Replace

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, ssh, command

I'm trying to replace

```
</url></loc>
```

with

```
</loc></url>
```

in all my files but nothing seems to be working.  Is there a way to do this via command line, perl, etc.?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Note that many versions of `sed` do not recognize `-i`.  But you can do exactly the same with perl:

```
find . -exec perl -i -pe 's|(</url>)(</loc>)|$2$1|g' {} \;
```

Perl has a big advantage over sed in that it will be much easier to expand this to include occurrences of the two tags that are spread over multiple lines.

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's|(</url>)(\s*)(</loc>)|$3$2$1|g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out `sed`:

```
sed -i 's|</url></loc>|</loc></url>|g' <filenames>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sed:

```
sed -i 's/<\/url><\/loc>/<\/loc><\/url>/g' yourfiles.*
```

To replace other tags:

```
sed -E -i 's/<\/(url|what|ever)><\/(loc|any|other)>/<\/\2><\/\1>/g' yourfiles.*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "yourname*" -exec sed -i 's/<\/url><\/loc>/<\/loc><\/url>/g' '{}' ';'
```